# Can someone very intuitively explain why the cross-product works, with respect to proportions?

Tags: education

Note: unrelated to matrices.

I have to teach this concept, and I want to know what is the best way to show that the cross product is always equal if the two fractions are equal.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't call it the cross product. The standard term is cross-multiplication, and it refers to the process of doing the multiplication, not the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** Let $b$ and $d$ be nonzero. Then:
>   $$
> \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \iff ad = bc
> $$

**Proof:** Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}
&\iff bd\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = bd\left(\frac{c}{d}\right) &\text{multiply both sides by $bd$} \\
&\iff ad\left(\frac{b}{b}\right) = bc\left(\frac{d}{d}\right) &\text{by rearranging} \\
&\iff ad = bc &\text{by cancellation}
\end{align*}

Comment: Perfectamundo!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\frac ab=\frac cd$ If you multiply both sides by $bd$, which cannot be $0$ if the fractions make sense, you have $ad=bc$